# How to enable F5 for own view/explorer?

Tags: refresh, eclipse-plugin

I have a view (`ViewPart`) based on my own objects (with an `ITreeContentProvider`). How can I enable the F5-key and the corresponding menu entry (File -> Refresh) for this view? Currently it's disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refresh action is a retargetable action with id `IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_REFRESH` and usually implemented with `org.eclipse.ui.actions.RefreshAction`. So something like this in your `ViewPart`:

```
RefreshAction refreshResourcesAction = new RefreshAction(getViewSite());
refreshResourcesAction.setActionDefinitionId(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_REFRESH);

IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();

bars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.REFRESH.getId(), refreshResourcesAction);
```

`RefreshAction` expects the selection to be `IResource` based objects - if that is not the case in your view you will have to do more work.

Comment: Yes, I have my own objects - not IResources. I've updated the question.

Comment: For the most part the answer stands, you just need to write your own refresh action.